# Dynamic height for StaggeredGridView is not working in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, staggered-gridview

I wanted to build a StaggeredGridView with a banner video at the 0th index and 2 cards at each row. But the video is not filling the screen width, because the height for every row is the same.

Here is what I am doing.

```
static final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
  "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4");

static final chewieController = ChewieController(
videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
autoPlay: true,
looping: true,
allowMuting: true,
allowFullScreen: false,);

final playerWidget = Chewie(
controller: chewieController,);
```

Code for building Widget:

```
Widget buildStaggeredListing(BuildContext context) {
return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return playerWidget;
    }
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          index.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return StaggeredTile.count(2, 1);
    }
    return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);
  },
);
```

}

Screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNK96.png)

Update: according to sagar acharya's answer, I used

```
if (index == 0) {
      return StaggeredTile.fit(1);
   }
    return StaggeredTile.fit(2);
```

and this is what is happening: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eV3d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if this code works:

```
staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return StaggeredTile.fit(2);
    }
    return StaggeredTile.count(1,1);
  },
```

Comment: no brother. I updated my question with what I have tried from your suggestion.

Comment: can you just make StaggeredTile.fit(2) for index 0 , and use this if index is not 0 : return StaggeredTile.count(1, 1);

Comment: That works. Thank you. Please edit your answer and I can approve it.